# Cannot log in to careers 2.0

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

from few days on-wards I cannot log in to careers 2.0 website via OpenId/email account. It gives the following error. I'm getting this continuously.

Hope careers 2.0 corrects this ASAP.

[image]

Comment: They want to show that damn cool graphics to you ... :D btw its working fine to me .. please try once more

Comment: thats true in some manner @NullPointer

Comment: I have tried for so many days and I've tried in all the browsers, but it still doesnt work :( @NullPointer

Comment: Did you... try sending an email using the clearly visible "support" link? =)

Comment: i think the support is for paid customers or so @J.Steen

Comment: Ah, I see. It even says on the support page. Oh well. =)

Comment: anyway so far i cant login to it. I wonder how long will they take to fix this

Comment: All you can do is wait for an able person to notice this post, sorry to say.

Comment: Yep that's the sad part waiting.............. and not knowing what will happen :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try again, you should now be able to log in. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I can log in now. +1 for the good work